# How to generate uuid in node.js with cluster mode for postgres pk

Tags: node.js, postgresql, uuid

I'm not sure how to generate or what version of [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) to chose that will generate unique uuid on node with [cluster mode](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) for postgres database primary key.

As i can see there can be used two differences:

1. Pm2/node process id to differentiate handlers: 1,2,3 ... max CPU cores.
2. Time when uuid is generated to generate unique uuid in each process.

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL plug-in for generate PK on DB sude

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev  But what version of generator to use for postgres cluster? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html

Comment: For single PostgreSQL server `uuid_generate_v4()` is good enough